# PHP Regex Separate Number from String

Tags: php, regex, string, numbers

I have the following string: `01SOMECOMPANY` and I want to end up with `01 SOMECOMPANY`. How do I do this using regular expressions?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: You don't need regex to inset a space at `index = 2`. A better explanation and some more use cases would help your cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex could look something like this:

```
  (\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)
```

You could then use the capturing groups in the replacement expression, with a space between them.

```
  $1 $2
```

Answer (score 2):

regular expression would be "/^([0-9]+)(.+)/"  and the replacement "\1 \2" or "$1 $2". Can't remember if PHP uses \1 or $1 to refer the first match in regexp.

Comment: Both work, you canfind this here in the manual: http://php.net/preg_replace - see the *replacement* parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I used [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) function to separate components of the string. And then joined the elements, using space as a separator:

```
<?php
$str = '01string44str';
$elements = preg_split('/(\d+)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$output = implode(" ", $elements);
print $output;
```

This prints:

> 01 string 44 str

More effective solution will be using [preg_replace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function with a back reference:

```
<?php
$str = '01string44str';
$output = preg_replace('/(\d+)/', '$1 ', $str);
print $output;
```

This prints a little different result:

> 01 string44 str

Not sure, whether you need a space between 'string' and '44'. For your string '01SOMECOMPANY' it works correctly though.

Answer (score 0):

The following example will explain to you.

```
$string = "01SOMECOMPANY";
preg_match('/^([0-9]*)(.*)/i', $string, $matches);
echo $matches[1]." ".$matches[2];
```

The result:
`01 SOMECOMPANY`